# Open subspaces of locally compact Hausdorff spaces are locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be locally compact and Hausdorff. I want to prove the following:

> If $Y\subset X$ is open then $Y$ is locally compact.

I have proved that closed subsets of $X$ are locally compact, but how can one prove this?

I also want to use these two lemmas to conclude the following:

> If $Y\subset X$ is locally closed then $Y$ is locally compact.

Answer (score 15):

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.

To show that an open subspace $Y$ of $X$ is itself locally compact, given $x \in Y$ fix open neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ in $X$ such that

- $\overline{U}$ is compact. (It is possible to do this because $X$ is locally compact.)
- $\overline{V} \subseteq Y$. (It is possible to do this because locally compact Hausdorff spaces are regular.)

Now $U \cap V$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ (and also in $Y$). Furthermore

- as $\overline{U \cap V} \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq Y$, then $\operatorname{cl}_Y ( U \cap V ) = \overline{U \cap V} \cap Y = \overline{U \cap V}$.
- as $\overline{U \cap V}$ is a closed subset of the compact $\overline{U}$, it is also compact.

Since you already know that closed subspaces of $X$ are locally compact, it now easily follows that locally closed subspaces of $X$ are locally compact. Recall that being locally closed in $X$ is equivalent to being of the form $U \cap F$ where $U \subseteq X$ is open and $F \subseteq X$ is closed. So $F$ is locally compact as a closed subspace of $X$, and $U \cap F$ is locally compact as an open subspace of $F$.

---

It may be worth mentioning that locally compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are locally closed. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326145/8348) and its answer.) And so in a locally compact Hausdorff space, being a locally compact subspace and being a locally closed subspace are equivalent notions.

Answer (score 7):

I know this proof doesn't really use the preliminary results you wanted to use, but I can't resist.

Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff. Then $X$ has a one-point compactification $\alpha X=X\cup\{\infty\}$ and a Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$.  The identity map on $X$ extends to a map $\beta X\to \alpha X$, and the remainder $\beta X \setminus X$ maps to ${\infty}$.  Thus $X$ is open in $\beta X$.  If $Y$ is open in $X$ then $Y$ is also open in $\beta X$. It is easy to see that open subsets of compact Hausdorff spaces are locally compact, so there you go!

Answer (score 1):

The previous proofs were too complicated and rather confusticate the problem.
Instead you can simply follow your nose:

---

We follow the definition of a **locally compact space** as it should be:*
Every point has a **neighborhood basis of compact subsets.**

Having settled our grounds, let's get straight to the proof:
Consider a locally compact space and an open subspace $X\subseteq Y$.

Let $x\in U\subseteq X$ be a neighborhood of $x\in X$.
Assume wlog that $U$ is open in $X$ (e.g. $U=X\cap V$).
So also $U$ open in $Y$ **as by assumption $X\subseteq Y$ open!**

**By assumption $Y$ is locally compact.**
So we may sandwich this in $x\in L\subseteq U$ with $L$ a compact nbhd of $x\in Y$.
Since this took place in $L\subseteq X$, the restricted neighborhood remains $L\cap X=L$.
This defines the desired compact nbhd.

---

**Two small remarks for common agreement:*

- Generally these are not open and possibly not closed.
- Hausdorffness does not play any role in our proof. It only serves to characterise (for the original space $Y$) that the existence of single compact neighborhood may be sufficient for local compactness.

Comment: Sorry, my definition of locally compact space is: X is locally compact if every point of X has a neighborhood whose closure is compact. I didn't learn the concept about "basis". Are these 2 definitions the same? How do I use your proof by using my definition?

Comment: In the general possibly non-Hausdorff case: Locally compact should be rather taken to be the definition using compact neighbourhood bases since compact sets may not be closed which might sweep some relevant examples under the rug. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1116174/79762